# How can I make the Index of VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP dynamic to search an ever expanding pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a pivot table that I need to reference on another tab in Google Sheets, in the pivot table I have all purchases made grouped by month. (See the first picture attached) as time goes on, every new month will add a column to my pivot table.

On the other tab, I have a 12 month summary that shows either the current year month expenditures for that category, or the month from the last year (depending on the current date). (See the second picture attached).

I've not been able to figure a way to return the category month total automatically by searching the pivot table based on the date in the summary.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your existing code with the error you have encountered? Also please provide a link of your sheet to work on with your desired output.

Comment: don't reference the pivot table ever, just reference the underlying data that supplies the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did figure out the answer to my question. I ended up using Index and match together. here was my final formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX('X2'!$G$4:$EP,MATCH($I7,'X2'!$G$4:$G,0),MATCH(J$6,'X2'!$G$4:$EP$4,0)))
```

thanks to all who commented!